# Is The Leo Moll Unofficial BTSync PPA Still Maintained?

Tags: 14.04, btsync

I ask because last build was two months ago & the current BTSync is outdated. I am trying to autostart BTSync & this seems the best way.

Comment: Have you contacted the PPA maintainer?

Comment: You will need to contact the owner of a PPA, to have any maintenance or related questions about the PPA, answered.

Comment: He has no email on the PPA site.

Comment: I will delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For questions and bugs with software in this PPA please contact [Leo Moll](https://launchpad.net/~tuxpoldo).

That's just after the "Adding this PPA to your system" section on the [PPA's information page](https://launchpad.net/~tuxpoldo/+archive/ubuntu/btsync). If you click the link to go to his Launchpad profile, you'll find contact information.

That isn't always the case. Sometimes it's a group (look at the commits to see who's active). Occasionally you'll find somebody without contact information... Unfortunately in those situations you're stuck.